# Limit JMS connections created by Spring JmsListener

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have total 4 `JmsListener` defined in my application. I am using `DefaultMessageListenerContainerFactory` and have concurrency set to `25-75`. I see my application is creating lot of JMS connections and exhausting the limit. Is there a way I can limit this connection?

```java
JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> createJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory cf,DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, cf);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
    factory.setBackOff(new FixedBackOff());
    return factory; 
}
```

Here is how I use it in listener.

```java
@Bean(name = "containerFactory")
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
    //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
}
   
@JmsListener(destination = "queue1", containerFactory = "containerFactory", concurrency = "25-75")
```

I have my 6 instances of my application running. I need to restrict JMS connection limit per instance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your connection factory in a `SingleConnectionFactory` and they will all share the same connection.

Comment: thanks Garry. Is there a way I can print something in log when connection is created? How does listener listener decides to create new connection? I see 30-40 connections being made from single instance and that's surprising.

Comment: As I said, don't use the IBM factory directly, wrap it in a `SingleConnectionFactory` and use that in the container factory.